# Consequences/existence of problems without any "optimal" algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, complexity-classes, time-complexity

Let $P$ be some kind of "problem" such as addition or graph coloring, that has an input size $n$. Let $S_P$ denote the set of algorithms $A_1, A_2, \dots$ which deterministically solve $P$. Based off this, let $S'_P$ denote the set of "optimal" algorithms that solve $P$, in other words:

$$S'_P :=  \{A_i ∈ S_P | \nexists A_j ∈ S_P  \textrm{ s.t.} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{O(A_i)}{O(A_j)} = 0 \}$$

Is there an example of a problem when $S_P$ is non-empty, but $S'_P = \emptyset$? Also, are there any significant implications concerning the existence/non-existence of such a problem?

Comment: As far as we know, even SAT might not have an "optimal algorithm"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Blum's speedup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%27s_speedup_theorem), proved in 1967, shows that there is such a problem $P$ that has no optimal algorithm.

The problem $P$ doesn't look all that much like addition or graph coloring - it's defined in terms of sets of machines $Z_i$, the primitive recursive functions $\phi_i(n)$ computed by the $i$th machine, and "step-counting functions" $\Phi_i(n)$ (which count how many steps the $i$th machine took to execute its function), and involves search over the latter in order to achieve the desired properties :).

It's a good reminder that the space of algorithms is large and counterintuitive - especially when the inputs and outputs are themselves programs. But you're also not likely to see this sort of weirdness *until* your inputs are programs, either, and maybe not even then depending on what you're trying to do with them...

Reference:

Blum, Manuel. "A machine-independent theory of the complexity of recursive functions." *Journal of the ACM (JACM)* 14.2 (1967): 322-336.